# Integrating an inverse sum of roots

Tags: calculus, integration

I recently thought about this question, and I attempted to solve it
$$I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x+\sqrt{x} + \cdots + \sqrt[n]{x}} \mathop{ dx}$$

for $n\ge 2$. I've made next to no progress, although I was able to deal with the case $n=2$ which is fairly standard. I am unsure how to proceed in the general case and am wondering if there is a general closed form. It seems unlikely to me that there is, but I have no reason to strongly believe so.

Comment: If you substitute $x=y^{n!}$ then it reduces to a rational integral, but with denominator of degree $n!$.

Comment: What is the context of this question?

Comment: There is no context, I just thought of it on a car journey. I have no idea why it popped into my head.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thats good trick, it seems that factoring the denominator from there would be hard though (i was considering a rather ridiculous partial fractions decomposition). Do you think it could be algorithmically expressed? I suspect the closed form is tractable if we use about $n!$ additions, multiplicatoins, etc...

Comment: If $n=3$, then what is $\sqrt{x}$? You need $\sqrt[j]{x}$ to be simple for $j=1,2,\dots,n$. You could pick $x=y^m$ where $m$ is the least common multiple of $1,2,3,\dots,n$. @YuriyS